# How to iterate through array of arrays on Rails template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, ruby-on-rails-4, view

I've got an array in the following form:

```
[["First", ["a", "b", "c"]], ["Second", ["d", "e"]], ["Third", ["g", "h", "i"]]]
```

Is there a way to somehow display this information on a Rails template using iterators? I need something like this:

**First** - a, b, c

**Second** - d, e,

**Third** - g, h, i.

Or this is impossible and I should modify the initial array form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @Iceman That's the case, I have no idea how to execute this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifing the main array you could try with `each_with_index` inside `each` for the main array of arrays, then checking for the first value you can skip it and get the array of letters:

```
array = [["First", ["a", "b", "c"]], ["Second", ["d", "e"]], ["Third", ["g", "h", "i"]]]

array.each do |main|
  main.each_with_index do |value, index|
    next if index.zero?
    p value 
  end
end
# => ["a", "b", "c"]
#    ["d", "e"]
#    ["g", "h", "i"]
```

Or if you want to access it as a hash it'd be easier:

```
array = [["First", ["a", "b", "c"]], ["Second", ["d", "e"]], ["Third", ["g", "h", "i"]]]
array.to_h.each do |_, value|
  p value
end
# => ["a", "b", "c"]
#    ["d", "e"]
#    ["g", "h", "i"]
```

Comment: You're welcome, I think it'd be better to iterate as a hash (: